# How to create domain entities for a NoSQL application

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to create an application that makes use of a NoSQL database in such a way to it plays nicely with my domain entities.

Right now when I create a "domain entity" for MongoDB then I have to define it something like this:

```
public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [BsonElement("Username")]
    public string Username {get;set;}

    [BsonElement("Email")]
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

But this means my entity isn't persistence ignorant. So how can I achieve that when using a NoSQL database like MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a POCO class in your domain like this

```
namespace MyApp.Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and define the same class for each persistence type, for example MongoDB

```
namespace MyApp.MongoDb
{
    public class User
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You business logic will interact with your domain classes through repository interfaces, and when you persist data, you just need copy the instance over.

You don't have to write copying data code manually because [automapper](http://automapper.org/) can help you with that. Alternatively, you can use my simplified code to copy data between domain classes below:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Copy public fields from an instance of the source type TV to an instance of the destination type T.
        ///  A source property will be copied if there is a property in the destination type with the same name.
        /// For instance, TV.Name will be copied to T.Name
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The destination type</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TV">The source type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="input">The source data</param>
        /// <param name="existingInstance">The instance that we want to copy values to, if it is null a new instance will be created</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of type T</returns>
        public static T CopyFields< TV,T>(TV input, T existingInstance=null)where  T:class where TV:class 
        {
            var sourcePublicFields = typeof (TV).GetProperties();

            var instance =existingInstance ?? Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            var destinationPublicFields = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            Debug.WriteLine("Copying data from source type {0} to destination type {1}", typeof(TV), typeof(T));

            foreach (var field in sourcePublicFields)
            {
                var destinationField = destinationPublicFields.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Name == field.Name);
                if (destinationField == null || destinationField.PropertyType != field.PropertyType)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No Destination Field matched with the source field. Source Field  name {0}, source field type {1} ", field.Name, field.PropertyType);
                    continue;
                }

                var sourceValue = field.GetValue(input);
                //Set the value
                destinationField.SetValue(instance,sourceValue);

            }


            return instance;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entities can be POCO objects.

Almost all your rules you can resolve by using `ConvetionRegistry`.
Fox example this code set Id as string and ignore extra fields.

```
var convention = new ConventionPack { 
    new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true), 
    new IdGeneratorConvention() };
ConventionRegistry.Register("CubeConventions", convention, x => true);

public class IdGeneratorConvention : ConventionBase, IPostProcessingConvention
{
    public void PostProcess(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
        var idMemberMap = classMap.IdMemberMap;
        if (idMemberMap == null || idMemberMap.IdGenerator != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        idMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    }
}
```